# How to capture any pattern groups between optional patterns?

Tags: javascript, regex

What would be the best approach to match an optional pattern at the end of a string, after an any pattern, using Regex in Javascript? Is there a way to make an optional pattern inclusive when it comes at the end of the string and after an any pattern?

My Regex:

```
'{any:any}'.match(/\{?(.+):(.+)\}?/);
```

Current Result:

```
['{any:any}', 'any', 'any}', index: 0, input: '{any:any}', groups: undefined]
```

Expected Result:

```
['{any:any}', 'any', 'any', index: 0, input: '{any:any}', groups: undefined]
```

Comment: `\{?([^}]+):([^}]+)\}?`?

Comment: You'll want to use non-greedy repetition: `/\{?(.+?):(.+?)\}?/`. And possibly add anchors like  `/^\{?(.+?):(.+?)\}?$/`

Answer (score 0):

If you want to keep the curly's optional, you can use 2 capture groups in combination with a negated character class:

```
{?([^{}:]+):([^{}:]+)}?
```

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/cO7gJX/1)

```js
console.log('{any:any}'.match(/{?([^{}:]+):([^{}:]+)}?/));
```

If you don't want to cross newlines, you can exclude them:

```
{?([^{}:\n]+):([^{}:\n]+)}?
```

Comment: It works if we do not consider that the 'any' pattern must include any character, including '{}'.

Comment: @JeffPal If you want to exclude the least amount of characters in between, you can first exclude the `:` and then exclude the `}` after it. `{?([^:]+):([^:}]+)}?` https://regex101.com/r/HlIQxY/1

Comment: @JeffPal Or considering the end of the string `{?([^:]+):(.*?)}?$` See https://regex101.com/r/PW9BeP/1